# What does MYSQLI_NUM mean and do?

Tags: php, mysql

I just wanted a little bit of information on MYSQLI_NUM. And is it part of PHP or MySQL.

Answer (score 33):

MYSQLI_NUM is a constant in PHP associated with a mysqli_result.  If you're using mysqli to retrieve information from the database, MYSQLI_NUM can be used to specify the return format of the data.  Specifically, when using the fetch_array function, MYSQLI_NUM specifies that the return array should use numeric keys for the array, instead of creating an associative array.  Assuming you have two fields in your database table, "first_field_name" and "second_field_name", with the content "first_field_content" and "second_field_content"...

```
$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
```

fetches each row of the result like this:

```
array(
    0 => "first_field_content",
    1 => "second_field_content"
);
```

Alternatively...

```
$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

fetches an array like this:

```
array(
    "first_field_name" => "first_field_content",
    "second_field_name" => "second_field_content"
);
```

Using the constant MYSQLI_BOTH will fetch both.

Answer (score 4):

It is a PHP constant used in [mysqli_fetch_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

This tells the function that you want it to return a record from your results as a numerically indexed array instead of an associative one (MYSQLI_ASSOC) or both (MYSQLI_BOTH).

Alternatively, you can just use mysqli_fetch_row() to do the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

Google is your friend! ;)  MYSQLI_NUM is a PHP constant used by the mysqli database extension;

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.constants.php

Comment: My point was that the question was very easily answered by making some effort, rather than just asking for help. FYI, I feel the down-vote unnecessary as I didn't just say RTFM, I provided a link that contained the necessary answer.