# Single Value Mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to write a function that will check for a single value in the db using mysqli without having to place it in an array.  What else can I do besides what I am already doing here?

```
function getval($query){
    $mysqli = new mysqli();
    $mysqli->connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DB);
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    $value = $mysqli->fetch_array;
    $mysqli->close();
    return $value;
}
```

Answer (score 44):

How about

```
$name = $mysqli->query("SELECT name FROM contacts WHERE id = 5")->fetch_object()->name;
```

Comment: This is the shortest line of code for getting a mysqli result value.

Comment: This assumes that the scalar being returned has a known field name. This is not consistent with OP's code, which passes in ANY query (that is expected to return a single value; a "scalar" query).  It might not even be a query of a record field - it could be returning a count, or even a system variable.

Comment: In case the `query` fails, this will cause a `Fatal error` (Call to a member function fetch_object() on boolean).

Answer (score 28):

The mysql extension could do this using mysql_result, but mysqli has no equivalent function as of today, afaik. It always returns an array.

If I didn't just create the record, I do it this way:

```
$getID = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($link, "SELECT userID FROM users WHERE something = 'unique'"));
$userID = $getID['userID'];
```

Or if I did just create the record and the userID column is AI, I do:

```
$userID = mysqli_insert_id($link);
```

Comment: Or change `assoc` to `array` and then you can do `$getID[0]`

Comment: And nobody, nobody, nobody cares that the only meaningful part of this long-sought "one-liner" is gone far beyond visible screen...

Comment: downvoted solely because `fetch_object()` existed many years before this answer,  which returns a simple object, which means that at the time you wrote this mysqli did have a better option. Also your answer is written in procedural commands while OP's question was written via object-based mysqli.

Comment: This assumes that the scalar being returned has a known field name. This is not consistent with OP's code, which passes in ANY query (that is expected to return a single value; a "scalar" query).  It might not even be a query of a record field - it could be returning a count, or even a system variable.

Answer (score 7):

Always best to create the connection once at the beginning and close at the end. Here's how I would implement your function.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli();
$mysqli->connect(HOSTNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE);

$value_1 = get_value($mysqli,"SELECT ID FROM Table1 LIMIT 1");
$value_2 = get_value($mysqli,"SELECT ID FROM Table2 LIMIT 1");

$mysqli->close();

function get_value($mysqli, $sql) {
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $value = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
    return is_array($value) ? $value[0] : "";
}
```

Comment: is MYSQLI_NUM a constant?

Comment: Yes, it is. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684993/what-does-mysqli-num-mean-and-do 

From php.net, "This optional parameter is a constant indicating what type of array should be produced from the current row data. The possible values for this parameter are the constants MYSQLI_ASSOC, MYSQLI_NUM, or MYSQLI_BOTH."

Comment: this answer, and the more recent answers by John and rybo111, are the only ones that directly address OP's code.  OP's question shows a method that accepts ANY scalar-returning query -- does not require knowing name of a field to be returned.

Answer (score 5):

Here's what I ended up with:

```
function get_col($sql){
  global $db;
  if(strpos(strtoupper($sql), 'LIMIT') === false) {
    $sql .= " LIMIT 1";
  }
  $query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
  return $row[0];
}
```

This way, if you forget to include `LIMIT 1` in your query (we've all done it), the function will append it.

Example usage:

```
$first_name = get_col("SELECT `first_name` FROM `people` WHERE `id`='123'");
```

Comment: Minor issue: The query could contain `limit` (lowercase) instead of `LIMIT`. So if you use the part of the answer involving `LIMIT`, might want to make the test `if (strpos($sql, 'LIMIT') === false && strpos($sql, 'limit') === false) {`

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Good spot - fixed using `strtoupper()`.

Comment: Let's just hope that there is no string literal in the SQL that happens to contain the string "limit".

Comment: @trincot True, it was an afterthought - the if statement could look for `LIMIT N` (where N is 0-9) using regexp instead.

Answer (score 3):

Even this is an old topic, I don't see here pretty simple way I used to use for such assignment:

```
list($value) = $mysqli->fetch_array;
```

you can assign directly more variables, not just one and so you can avoid using arrays completely. See the php function [list()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) for details.

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost,

#### Such a function should support prepared statements

Otherwise it will be [horribly insecure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/285587).

Also, such a function should never connect on its own, but accept an **existing connection variable** as a parameter.

Given all the above,  only acceptable way to call such a function would be be like

```
$name = getVal($mysqli, $query, [$param1, $param2]);
```

allowing `$query` to contain only placeholders, while the actual data has to be added separately. Any other variant, including all other answers posted here, should never be used.

```
function getVal($mysqli, $sql, $values = array())
{
    $stm = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    if ($values)
    {
        $types = str_repeat("s", count($values));
        $stm->bind_param($types, ...$values);
    }
    $stm->execute();
    $stm->bind_result($ret);
    $stm->fetch();
    return $ret;
}
```

Which is used like this

```
$name = getVal("SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = ?", [$id]);
```

and it's the only proper and safe way to call such a function, while all other variants lack security and, often, readability.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't completely avoid the array but dispenses with it in one line.

```
function getval($query) {
    $mysqli = new mysqli();
    $mysqli->connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DB);
    return $mysqli->query($query)->fetch_row()[0];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
$last = $mysqli->query("SELECT max(id) as last FROM table")->fetch_object()->last;
```

Cheers

Comment: This assumes that the scalar being returned has a known field name. This is not consistent with OP's code, which passes in ANY query (that is expected to return a single value; a "scalar" query).  It might not even be a query of a record field - it could be returning a count, or even a system variable.