# Simple MySQL call to select an integer at a specific key not working?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, connection

I have this PHP:

```
    <?php

    $client_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $connection = new mysqli("localhost", "MyNotSoSecretUsername", "MySuperSecretPassword", "MyNotSoSecretDatabaseName");

    if ($connection->connect_error) {
         die("Connection failed: " . $Connection->connect_error);
    }

    $check_emails_sent_query = "SELECT `emails` FROM `email-ips` WHERE `ip`='11.111.111.111'";
    $check_emails_sent_result = $connection->query($check_emails_sent_query);

    echo $check_emails_sent_result;

    ?>
```

This is a small piece of a much larger function on my site. This snippet is simply intended to get the value of the "emails" column (Which is an `int` column if that makes a difference) of my table where the IP matches the client's IP.

I added a fake entry for 11.111.111.111 in my database, and used the exact same query on PHPmyAdmin's SQL console. I got a result on the PHPmyAdmin console, but nothing is echoed here.

I have also checked that the connection is good, as you can see in my code. Additionally, I pasted another query from another part of my function, which retrieved its data just fine.

AS stupid or obvious as it may be, I can't seem to figure out why this particular query out of almost twenty won't retrieve its data?

Comment: `$check_emails_sent_result` is an object. What do you expect to be printed?

Comment: Mysqli->query() should return an object rather than a variable that you can echo out. From that object you can get the value of emails

Comment: A quick Google and a look through some of the PHP documentation didn't yield anything on mysqli objects, just how to use object-oriented mysqli. What do I request from the object in order to get my value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysqli `query()` returns and object. Using the object:

```
<?php

$client_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$connection = new mysqli("localhost", "MyNotSoSecretUsername", "MySuperSecretPassword", "MyNotSoSecretDatabaseName");

if ($connection->connect_error) 
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $Connection->connect_error);
}

$check_emails_sent_query = "SELECT `emails` FROM `email-ips` WHERE `ip`='11.111.111.111'";

if ($check_emails_sent_result = $connection->query($check_emails_sent_query)) 
{ 
    while($obj = $check_emails_sent_result->fetch_object())
    { 
        $echo $obj->emails; 
    } 
} 

?>
```

You could use `fetch_row()` instead of `fetch_object()`.

Documentation for the object is here:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php

Comment: Judging by the down-vote on my question, I should have stopped using deprecated functions and got on the MySQLi train a while ago. I found a "shorthand" version to get the single value I was looking for on another question...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456707/single-value-mysqli...I'm having hard time believing that the "improved" version of MySQL would make it such a pain to return single values. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Personally I am not that keen on trying to turn it into shorthand as much as possible (beyond for amusement), so explicitly using extra lines of code would be fine with me.

Answer (score 1):

[mysqli_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

> Returns `FALSE` on failure. For successful `SELECT`, `SHOW`, `DESCRIBE` or
>   `EXPLAIN` queries `mysqli_query()` will return a `mysqli_result` object. For
>   other successful queries `mysqli_query()` will return `TRUE`.

You can get your email by using

```
if ($result = $connection->query($check_emails_sent_query)) {

    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0]);
    }
}
```