# can't echo out an int variable

Tags: php, mysqli

I've tried to use the solutions presented in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456707/single-value-mysqli),
to no avail, so I used this:

```
  $stat = "SELECT MAX(employee_id) FROM employees";
 $querysult = intval($connection, $stat);
```

Where `employee_id` is an int(3) in the database table.
For some reason, the above code actually gets the values from the database, despite there not being a `mysqli_query()` in sight. But my question is about what I did immediately after, which was

```
echo "Id: " . $querysult;
```

and which output nothing but

```
Id:
```

and no number. I've also tried casting the number to a string, and concatenating it to an empty string before the echo statement.

Comment: "For some reason, the above code actually gets the values from the database, despite there not being a mysqli_query() in sight. " NO clearly it does not

Comment: Use an alias inside a loop and echo that row, *done like dinner*.

Comment: _I've tried to use the solutions presented in this question_ But first you have to master querying the database. [Start here, Its a secret source of information about PHP, almost nobody else knows about it, so it can be our secret. Its even in 11 languages](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: sure but actually run the query to @Fred-ii-

Comment: *si, signore* @Dagon

Comment: We need more information to be able to help you out

Comment: Dagon the query does work, since it gets the proper ID value (. Erick, I'm going to update it in an hour or so with a lot more code then. @RiggsFolly, I've been using that documentation, but it appears to be COMPLETELY useless as far as getting an individual value out of a database is concerned, since mysqli_result is a cryptic creature where none of the methods return proper types.

Answer (score 0):

***For some reason, the above code actually gets the values from the database, despite there not being a mysqli_query() in sight***

This of course is quite impossible, unless you are getting something from a previously executed query that uses the same variable names.

I think your main problem is that accessing the value of the query coded using just `SELECT MAX(employee_id)` will return a column with the name  `MAX(employee_id)` and that is not a valid PHP variable name. So what you have to do is give that column another name that is a valid PHP variables name using this syntax `SELECT MAX(employee_id) as max_empid` which renames the column to `max_empid`

I am assuming nothing so I will also include a connection to the database in my answer. You will need to replace the `my_user`, `my_password` and `my_db` values, or ignore the connection if you have already dont that somewhere else. I have also used the Object Oriented approach to MYSQLI, if you are using the proceedural calls, you may have to amend the code accordingly

```
// connect to your database
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

// build query and use an alias for the `MAX(employee_id)` 
// so you can easily use its name in the result set

$sql = "SELECT MAX(employee_id) as max_empid FROM employees";

// Now we must execute this query
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

// Now we must chech that the query worked
if ( $result === FALSE ) {
    echo sprintf( 'Query Failed: %s<br>%s', $sql, $mysqli->error);
    exit;
}

// now we must read one of the rows from the result set 
// produced by the ->query() command. 
// In this case there of course there is only one result row

$row = $result->fetch_object();

echo 'Id: ' . $row->max_empid;
```

Answer (score -1):

It may be because you are trying to convert a connection to an int value.

Try this 
 $connection = new mysqli();
 $querysult =mysqli_query(  $stat);

printf("Select returned %d.\n", $querysult->num_rows);