# Shorten down php mysqli response from array to single string

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I'm new to php/mysql and have run into this problem.

My code works, but the **$sqlResponse** gives out an array. In the example below (the current response) I only want '117'.

```
"sortingId":{"@last_sortingId := MAX(sortingId)":"117"}
```

My code is:

```
$sqlResponseGet = mysqli_query($this->db, "SELECT @last_sortingId := MAX(sortingId) FROM items");
$sqlResponse = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlResponseGet);

$this->response($this->json(array('sortingId' => $sqlResponse)), 200);
```

I tried various things, like $sqlResponseResult = $sqlResponse[0] and 
The answer from this [Single Value Mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456707/single-value-mysqli)

But can't get it to work

Really hope you can help me, thanks :)

Comment: you mean alias :-)

Comment: Turns out that wouldn't help either, since he just wants the result. :D

Comment: The alias would allow accessing the result from the array though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you should do is give an alias to the selected column:

```
$sqlResponseGet = mysqli_query($this->db, "SELECT @last_sortingId := MAX(sortingId) AS last_sortingId FROM items");
```

The result of `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` will be an associative array with this as the key, so you should index it.

```
$this->response($this->json(array('sortingId' => $sqlResponse['last_sortingId'])), 200);
```

Comment: Personally I like using assoc for all things. So I prefer this answer.

Comment: Oh great! That was what is was missing!. Thanks a lot!!.. But this gives me 'null' where IncredibleHats answer gave me the '117'? How can that be? :)

Comment: I don't know. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and see if there are any warnings.

Comment: Oh sorry!... hmmm just did some wrong copy/paste! Works brilliant, thanks a lot!!!!