# How to change the array key in while loop for the table on php

Tags: php

Suppose that I have a table like this:

```
id     name    age   birthplace
------------------------------
1      John    28   NY
2      Marry   23   LD
3      Mohamad 34   Malaysia
...
```

I do  `while loop` like this:

```
$query = "SELECT name, age, birthplace FROM tableName";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
$tableRows = array();
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
   $tableRows[] = $rows; 
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($tableRows);//Print the table rows from array
echo '</pre>';
```

I've got:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => John
        [age] => 28
        [birthplace] =>  NY

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Marry
        [age] => 23
        [birthplace] =>  Prozent Rabatt
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => 45521
        [age] => Bekleidung
        [birthplace] =>  LD
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => Mohamad
        [age] => 34
        [birthplace] =>  Malaysia 
    )
)
```

I would like to change the keys `name`, `age`, `birthplace` to `0`, `1`, `2` respectively.

I have read this link: 
[In PHP, how do you change the key of an array element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240660/in-php-how-do-you-change-the-key-of-an-array-element)
But it seems that I do not need it as the function because it looks so advanced to me.

I also read this link:
[PHP rename array keys in multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212948/php-rename-array-keys-in-multidimensional-array)
But it just meant to change one key in one array only as I tested for my case.

Your help is appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using MYSQLI_ASSOC its return associative array if you replace it with MYSQLI_NUM in mysqli_fetch_array() it will return a result as you ask

```
$query = "SELECT name, age, birthplace FROM tableName";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
$tableRows = array();
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM)){
   $tableRows[] = $rows; 
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($tableRows);//Print the table rows from array
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Oh, it returns `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => John
            [name] => John
            [1] => 28
            [age] => 28
        )
...
)`. That means each key is printed twice within its array. Any suggestion?

Comment: check it with MYSQLI_NUM. I also fix it in my answer

Comment: It throws an error like this `Undefined index: name`.

Comment: It works for me. is this your full code. if this is your full code try SQL query with SQL server because query can't find collum  as a name it throws error like this

Comment: ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684993/what-does-mysqli-num-mean-and-do